# Mapstruct NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapper, mapstruct

Проект на java 11.

Интерфейс создания маппера

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
    MyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);


    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "customerId", source = "customerId"),
            .....поля....,
    })
    TargetObject toRest(FromObject paymentCard);
```

Валиться в тесте на строке

```
MyMapper mapper = MyMapper.INSTANCE;
```

Зависимости

```
compileOnly('org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.2.0.Final')
compile('org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.2.0.Final')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16')
annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16')

testCompile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16')
testAnnotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16')
testCompile('org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.2.0.Final')
testAnnotationProcessor('org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.2.0.Final')
```

лог ошибки

строка 121 это инициализация мапера в тесте `MyMapper  mapper = MyMapper .INSTANCE;`

строка 25 это в самом мапере

```
MyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper .class);

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ru.pathToTest.MapperTest.mapToSoap(MapperTest.java:121)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for projectpath.MyMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:79)
    at my.project.MyMapper.<clinit>(MyMapper.java:25)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for projectpath.MyMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:93)
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:76)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: А полный лог ошибки?

Comment: прикрепил лог ошибки

Comment: Странно, что у Вас в коде `MyMapper`, а в логах `Mymapper`

Comment: опечатка. там реальный объект. я заменил уже в ручную на MyMapper. проблема в том что этот же код работал на java 8 и spring boot 1.5. на java 11 и Spring Boot 2.2 стали такие ошибки идти

Comment: Если у Вас `Java 11`, то возможно Вам не нужна зависимость `mapstruct-jdk8`.

Comment: Также советую Вам попробовать более новую версию  `MapStruct`

Comment: попробую спасибо

Comment: Да, скорей всего дело в подтянутой зависимости, возьмите самую свежую.

Comment: увы не помогло. 1.4.2 Final - такая же ошибка.